# R GLM Predict Error - factor has new levels

Tags: r, glm

I'm doing a basic logistic regression using glm()

I split the data into train and test, built the model using glm, and then tried running predict() using the test data.

Here is the code

```
data = read.csv('2022_data.csv')

data$A= as.factor(data$A)
data$B= as.factor(data$B)

# split train and test
df = sort(sample(nrow(data), nrow(data)*.8))
df_train = data[df,]
df_test = data[-df,]

# create model
model1 = glm(attrition ~ A+ B + C + D + E, data = df_train, family = binomial)

predict1 = predict(model1, df_test1, type='response')
```

I encountered

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor A has new levels
```

I understand that this error message means there is a value in column A that is not accounted for in the model. But I checked the unique values for column A in training and testing data, and both have the exact same values

```
levels(as.factor(df_test1$A))
levels(as.factor(df_train$A))
```

Both returns

```
[1] ""  "N" "Y"
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here

Update:

I checked the summary of the model and it shows only 1 dummy variable for A (i.e. AY, with AN being the reference). It seems that value "" is automatically being excluded by glm(). I changed "" to "no data", but this still occurs.

Comment: Great update Orvin.  A logistic regression as you are doing can really only have a response with two possible outcomes, e.g., success or failure. More than two outcomes, and you are talking about a multinomial regression.

Comment: Sconfluentus had a good suggestion, of doing table(df_test1) and table(df_train), which would be interesting to see.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about factors is that all the levels are stored in the metadata for the column whether or not the value is actually reflected in the data after subsetting.

So, you may have trained on data with two of three levels but not the third, that then shows up in the test data. (without seeing data and basic descriptive statistics I cannot be sure)

However, you can test this by running the following code to see what I mean:

```
x<-as.factor(x<-c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C"))
y<-x[1:2]
```

When you look at why this is what you see

```
 y
[1] A B
Levels: A B C
```

If you want to be sure that all values of the levels are reflected in your coefficients from training you should use a stratified sampling method to account for all levels in the data.

I would check before you go too far to see that there are enough of each level to be meaningful.

```
> table(x)
x
A B C 
4 4 4
```

If you only have a couple of one level you have bigger problems to consider.

You said that you changed "" to "No Data". If you did as a character/string then you need to re-level the factor to take the new category into consideration.

It might be best if you use :

```
library(plyr)
revalue(x, c(""="no_data"))
```

This way of converting will take into account the existing levels as it changes the value of that level. The values of levels persist even if you change a one set of values. It persists until you re-level)

Comment: I checked both df_train and df_test. I can confirm that "" exists in both df_train and df_test.

Comment: and both Y & N also exist? I ask because levels(x) will tell you what levels are available not if they have been USED by the data frame, that `table(x)` function will count instances

Comment: Yes both Y & N also exist

Comment: Yes you are right! I need to re-level the factor after I modified the column values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
library(forcats)
df_test1$A <- df_test1$A |> fct_drop(c(""))
```

Your error refers to model.frame.default. I am wondering if the "" levels aren't used in the model, and then found in test. Or you might want to assign "" levels to "Y" or "N".

Comment: I don't want to drop "" because it will skew the data. I changed "" to "no data" but it still produces the same error.

Comment: I think that you'd want to assign "" to NA, which means not available. When fitting the glm, you would usually set the na.action, typically to omit NAs, or for the fit to fail, so you won't gain anything by including them.